# open a new page using onClick but after that back to the previous page is not working

Tags: javascript, php

when I click a image. It's open a new page and a value pass through this click. It's working properly. but when I click back, It's do not show the previous page.
I use this code for click.

```
<img src="images/view.png" hspace="5" title="View" onClick="javascript:location.href='map_view.php?ad_id=<?php echo($row["ad_id"]); ?>'" style="cursor:pointer;" />
```

Comment: Hi Supriya, welcome to SO - Please take a read of this - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, your question is too broad.

Comment: I think you should better start with an PHP Tutorial and some easy Scripts.

But to answer to the Data from other Websites:

There are 2 ways 
1. ) Call the Page with a Curl Request and Parse the needed data.
2. ) Look if the Page has an API and use it.

Comment: can u send me some tutorial link on this topics?

Comment: The very first thing you have to start your project with `<html>` tag. After that, any problem come. Then, please come with your tried code. We will definitely help.

Comment: ya. its working.. thanks to all.

Comment: You could perhaps check it as answer

Answer (score 0):

In order to geocode any phisical address, or get its coordinates , you should use a geocoding API, being [**google maps api v3**](https://developers.google.com/maps/) the most popular, which by the way gives you a free starting point of up to 2500 daily requests.

There is a bunch of documentation and starting guides, the best are the google maps's own.

Of course you can geocode on PHP or Javascript. Its really easy.

Answer (score 0):

As other answer mentioned it is possible using google maps api, you can read more and get your own API KEY ([More info and Get api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)).

What you need is API key from google. This will help you fetching coordinates from given address.

I have made a little demonstration how it works it might be useful for other SO users.

By using following address 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=YOUR_ADDRESS&key=YOUR_API_KEY

It will return you JSON formatted results with coordinates.

Now we need to build a tiny address form and pass it it to PHP script to return us the results

**HTML Address form**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    Enter Address:<br>
    <input type="text" name="address">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP code**

```
if (isset($_POST["address"]))
{
    $addressInput = $_POST["address"];
    $address = str_replace(" ", "+", $addressInput);
} else
{
    // stack-overflow office address as default
    $address = "110+William+St,+28th+Floor+New+York,+NY+10038";

}

echo "Latitude and Longitude for address : " . str_replace("+", " ", $address) . '<br>';

$json = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $address . '&key=PUT_YOUR_OWN_API_KEY');
$data = json_decode($json, true);
//var_dump($data);

$getLat = $data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$getLng = $data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

echo 'latitude ' . $getLat . ', longitude ' . $getLng;
```

The above working code can be tested on this [link](http://dev.itbackyard.dk/projects/geolocation/).

Moving theses data to mysql database or what ever you want to use it for, is left to you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably use JavaScript for getting location of the user; not PHP. You can use HTML5 Geolocation for the purpose.

If you need to map the users location, pass the coordinates obtained using the HTML5 Geolocation API to Google Maps.

You may also need Modernizr to determine your users browser supports HTML5 Geolocation API.